# Object key values prints randomly

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects, key-value

everyone, I have an object like this

```
var days = {
  '2018-08-06': 1,
  '2018-08-07': 2, 
  '2018-08-08': 3,
  '2018-08-09': 4,
  '2018-08-10': 5   
};
```

I want to print the values of the keys so i tried

```
for( const day in days ) {
  console.log(days[day]);
}
```

It prints but sometimes it prints randomly. Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Your Object is not valid first of all. Please correct it (key value pair should be separated by comma). And looping through Object properties does print the values properly. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6bmct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods

**`Object.keys`**:  which will return an array of a given object's property names

```js
var days = {
  '2018-08-06': 1,
  '2018-08-07': 2, 
  '2018-08-08': 3,
  '2018-08-09': 4,
  '2018-08-10': 5   
};

Object.keys(days).forEach(function (day) {
   console.log(days[day])
});
```

**`Object.values`**:  which will return an array of a given object's property values

```
Object.values(days).forEach(function (day) {
  console.log(day)
})
```

**`Object.entries`**: Which will return an array of arrays containing key value pairs

```
Object.entries(days).forEach(function (entry) {
  console.log(entry[1])
})
```

And `for`  `in` should also work

```
for (let day in days) {
 if (days.hasOwnProperty(day)) {
   console.log(days[day])
 }
}
```